# Is it possible to label the area between grid lines rather than the grid lines

Tags: android, achartengine

Below is my bar graph.

What I am trying to achieve is positioning the xLabels between the grid lines. **Not aligned** to the X grid line LEFT\CENTER\RIGHT.

e.g. the label Mon needs to be placed in the middle of the 1st bar (bar with the value 20)

Is this possible using achart??

Would really appreciate the help.

This is its code:

```
public class AChartEngingFragment extends Fragment {
    private GraphicalView chartView;

    private String[] weekDays = {"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat","Sun"};


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_achart_engine, container, false);
        final Resources resources = getResources();
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.chart);

        chartView = createIntent();

        linearLayout.addView(chartView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


        return v;
    }

    public GraphicalView createIntent() {
        String[] titles = new String[]{"Benchmark line"};
        //List<double []> values = new ArrayList<double []>(); //as y1
        //values.add(new double[] {20.0, 10.0, 30.0, 25.0, 40.0});
        double[] y1 = new double[]{20.0, 10.0, 30.0, 25.0, 40.0, 15.0, 19.2};
        List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            x.add(new double[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6});
        }
        /*****************************************/
        List<double[]> lineValues = new ArrayList<double[]>(); //as values
        lineValues.add(new double[]{10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10});

        int[] colors = new int[]{Color.parseColor("#ea2e49")}; //pink


        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
        mRenderer.setPointSize(0);
        int length = mRenderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            XYSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = (XYSeriesRenderer) mRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
            seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(false);
            seriesRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
            seriesRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        }
        mRenderer.setOrientation(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        setChartSettings(mRenderer, "Average Customer Waiting Time", "Table Categories", "Minutes", 0, 7.5, 0, 30, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        mRenderer.setYLabels(10);
        mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(1, weekDays[0]);
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(2, weekDays[1]);
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(3, weekDays[2]);
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(4, weekDays[3]);
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(5, weekDays[4]);
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(6, weekDays[5]);
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(7, weekDays[6]);
        mRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(20f);

        mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);

        XYSeries ySeries = new XYSeries("Average Customer Waiting Time");
        ySeries.add(0.5, y1[0]);
        ySeries.add(1.5, y1[1]);
        ySeries.add(2.5, y1[2]);
        ySeries.add(3.5, y1[3]);
        ySeries.add(4.5, y1[4]);
        ySeries.add(5.5, y1[5]);
        ySeries.add(6.5, y1[6]);
        mRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);

        XYSeriesRenderer yRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        yRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#77c4d3")); //light blue

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = buildBarDataset(titles, x, lineValues);
        dataset.addSeries(0, ySeries);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(0, yRenderer);
        yRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        yRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(20); //text size on each bar

        String[] types = new String[]{BarChart.TYPE, LineChart.TYPE};
        final GraphicalView grfv = ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartView(getActivity(), dataset, mRenderer, types);
        return grfv;
    }

    protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[]{PointStyle.CIRCLE};
        mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(17);
        mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(25);
        mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setBarSpacing(-0.5);
        mRenderer.setPointSize(1f);
        mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEDED"));
        mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);

        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FBFBFC"));
        int length = colors.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { //build benchmark line
            XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer(); //change
            r.setColor(colors[i]);
            r.setPointStyle(styles[i]);
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        }
        return mRenderer;
    }

    protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer, String title, String xTitle, String yTitle, double xMin, double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor, int labelsColor) {
        mRenderer.setChartTitle(title);
        mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
        mRenderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
        mRenderer.setYTitle(yTitle);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);
        mRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{10, 65, 10, 15});
        mRenderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
        mRenderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);
        mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
        //mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
        mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
        mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
    }

    protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles, List<double[]> xValues, List<double[]> yValues) {
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        int length = titles.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            XYSeries series = new XYSeries(titles[i], 0);
            double[] xV = xValues.get(i);
            double[] yV = yValues.get(i);
            int seriesLength = xV.length;
            for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
                series.add(xV[k], yV[k]);
            }
            dataset.addSeries(series);
        }
        return dataset;
    }
}
```

[image: My Graph]

Comment: I am a little bit confused regarding your requirement, do you want the X-axis labels to be centered? (i.e) For eg, the label Mon needs to be placed in the middle of the 1st bar (bar with the value 20).

Comment: Fixed the description @VikramEzhil

Answer (score 0):

You need to update values at

```
    ySeries.add(1, y1[0]);
    ySeries.add(2, y1[1]);
    ySeries.add(3, y1[2]);
    ySeries.add(4, y1[3]);
    ySeries.add(5, y1[4]);
    ySeries.add(6, y1[5]);
    ySeries.add(7, y1[6]);
```

Change

```
    mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
```

And you'll get next result

[image]